# Cannot execute exe file

Tags: windows

I bump into one problem. Users cannot access certain exe file. Unless I rename the exe file or I simply put the exe file into different location then it will run fine. (Nothing happen when I double click on the file) The exe file is written using VB.net on .net framework 3.5 platform.

Comment: Does the file is not started if execute it from the command line - directly and via `cmd /c file.exe` / `start file.exe`?

Comment: Sounds like it might be being blocked or quarantined by anti-virus software. Do you have any running on this system?

Comment: Randomhero,, I've tried to uninstall all antivirus. It is still the same.

Comment: Akina, I am yet to try this. I will give it a try. The situation is if I rename the file or put it into another location, It would run.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be file configuration problem. I need to remove temporary file [appdata]\local folder